# tooltip creado por JS No se activa

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

que tal gente he creado una tabla con unas imagenes que se traducen a estados para los usuarios
estas imagenes tienen unos tooltips que funcionan bien, lo extraño es cuando le tengo que cambiar la imagen a ese td por otro para hacer el cambio de estado, cambia de imagen y texto pero no el tooltip se queda el default de html no el de bootstrap.

Este es el codigo que si muestra la imagen con el tooltip funcionando

`<td class='text-center' id='123'> <img src='img/bullet-red.png' data-bs-toggle='tooltip' data-bs-placement='top' title='Sin Ubicacion'></></td>`

luego vengo y por medio de js le agrego html al td asi:

`document.getElementById(123).innerHTML = '<label style="display: none;">3</label><img src="img/bullet-green.png" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Sin Ubicacion">';`

Answer (score 0):

Sacado [de la documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere). Después de haber agregado tu html, llama a:

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```